# Spring boot with restful services

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-mvc

I am new to `Spring boot`.

I am trying to write a code which uses post request as input.

I am getting this error when I try to send the post request through post rest client chrome plugin.

I am using **Maven build tool**.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1431079188726,
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/api/greetings" }
```

These are the classes.

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="webapi")
public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

**Greeting.java**

```
public class Greeting {

    private BigInteger id;
    private String text;

    public Greeting() {

    }

    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

**GreetingController.java**

```
@RestController

public class GreetingController {



    private static BigInteger nextId;
    private static Map<BigInteger, Greeting> greetingMap;


    private static Greeting save(Greeting greeting) {
        if (greetingMap == null) {
            greetingMap = new HashMap<BigInteger, Greeting>();
            nextId = BigInteger.ONE;

        }
        greeting.setId(nextId);
        nextId = nextId.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        greetingMap.put(greeting.getId(), greeting);
        return greeting;
    }

    static {
        Greeting g1 = new Greeting();
        g1.setText("Hello World");
        save(g1);

        Greeting g2 = new Greeting();
        g2.setText("Hola Mundo!");
        save(g2);

    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/greetings", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Greeting>> getGreetings() {
        Collection<Greeting> greetings = greetingMap.values();

        return new ResponseEntity<Collection<Greeting>>(greetings,
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/greetings/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

    public ResponseEntity<Greeting> getGreeting(
            @PathVariable("id") BigInteger id)
    {
        Greeting greeting = greetingMap.get(id);
        if (greeting == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(greeting, HttpStatus.OK);

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/greetings", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Greeting> createGreeting(
            @RequestBody Greeting greeting) {
        Greeting savedGreeting = save(greeting);
        return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(savedGreeting, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined mapping for path `/api/greetings` (with a parameter) as `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` so compiler is waiting for an json input but it is getting request of type `text/plain`(it mentions in stack trace) so from wherever you are passing request make sure content-type is "application/json".

as there is no mapping for `/api/greetings` for type `text/plain` this exception is thrown!

hope it helps!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The service is expecting a `application/json` `Content-Type` but its receiving an `text/plain` input.

What are you using to make the the post? if you are testing with Postman be sure to add `Content-Type` with `application/json` value in headers section.